# appending a list or tuple as value to a dictionary - or other solution to building a parent child relationship

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, ipython

From a Wordpress Database I retrieved the following tuples of menu items and their hierarchy.
The first value is the *name of the menu entry*, the second is the *item_id* and the third one is the *parent_id.*
If *parent_id* is 0, it is a top level element.

```
('Contact', 72, 0)
('Impressumm', 74, 0)
('Login', 227, 0)
('Company', 65, 0)
('References', 83, 65)
('AboutUs', 85, 65)
('Press', 87, 65)
('Solutions', 76, 0)
('ProductA', 242, 76)
('TechnologyA', 316, 242)
('Programming', 318, 242)
('Soldering', 321, 242)
('Welding', 323, 242)
('ProductB', 245, 76)
('Features', 326, 245)
('CADimport', 328, 245)
('Measuring', 331, 245)
('Surfaces', 333, 245)
('Editor', 248, 76)
('Simulation', 251, 76)
('Postprocessing', 254, 76)
('Manufacturing', 79, 0)
('Parts', 257, 79)
('Date', 259, 79)
('Tools', 261, 79)
('Communication', 263, 79)
('WebApps', 296, 79)
('Services', 69, 0)
('Training', 287, 69)
('Support', 285, 69)
('Forum', 289, 69)
('Events', 187, 0)
('Education', 269, 187)
('Workshops', 272, 187)
('Fairs', 275, 187)
('Seminars', 281, 187)
('Meetings', 278, 187)
```

For each tuple in the array of tuples I would like to add the full hierarchy.
E.g.

```
name,item_id,hierarchy
('Contact',72,'/Contact')
('Solutions',76,'/Solutions')
('Programming',318,'/Solutions/ProductA/Programming')
```

The unique key here is the *item_id* (second element). Names may appear possibly as duplicates or more than once.

I have the idea that this could be done using a dictionary in iPython. Since item_id may appear in the list of tuples (as parent_id for example), before they are defined, one has to go at least once through the array.

Could anyone give me some starting idea, how

1. iterate once through the array and build the dictionary
2. secondly, go through the dictionary by item_id (recursively?) to
   lookup    the parent_id and append the name to the second value,
   let's call it hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function which recursively find the parent of an item:

```
def getHierarchy(item_id,array_of_tuple,separator="/"):

  for i, (tuple_name, tuple_id, tuple_parent_id) in enumerate(array_of_tuple):
      if item_id == tuple_id:
          if tuple_parent_id == 0:
              return separator+tuple_name
          else:
              return separator+tuple_name+getHierarchy(tuple_parent_id,array_of_tuple)
  return ""
```

It produces:

```
>>print getHierarchy(289,array_of_tuples)

>>/Forum/Services
```

Comment: This is fine. I got it working. Minor corrections regarding the order and some missing parameters in you example:def getHierarchy(item_id,array_of_tuple,separator="/"):

  for i, (tuple_name, tuple_id, tuple_parent_id) in enumerate(map):
      if item_id == tuple_id:
          if tuple_parent_id == 0:
              return separator+tuple_name
          else:
              return getHierarchy(tuple_parent_id,array_of_tuple,separator)+ separator+tuple_name
  return ""

for name,item_id,parent_id in map:
    print getHierarchy(item_id,map,"/")

Comment: @Krischu You don't need to specifiy the separator when you call the function as it has a default value.

Comment: Could also made be a bit simpler: for name,item_id,parent_id in map:
    print getHierarchy(item_id,map,"/")